# Next badge select dialog broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, badge-progress

The "Select your next badge" dialog box is not displaying correctly. It looks like this:

[image: Next badge dialog]

Freehand circles, as requested:

[image: freehand circles ftw]

It seems to be an issue with `box-sizing`, because when it's `content-box`, it looks fine. I think the `width` and `height` rules for `.popup-badges .all-badge-progress .badge-progress` should be increased a little, for example:

```
.popup-badges .all-badge-progress .badge-progress {
  width: 214px;
  height: 96px;
}
```

Tested on the latest Chrome and Firefox on Linux Mint.

Comment: Uh, where's the problem? Please edit the image with some freehand circles.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317187/select-your-next-badge-layout-issue

Comment: @rene I think it should be asked here, because the bug is on the whole SE network.

Comment: Another example from PPCG, on latest Chrome on Windows 10: http://i.imgur.com/WTStKJV.png

Comment: I'm not saying it shouldn't be asked here. I only link to it so if a dev marks this status-completed they can easily find the other report and tag that as well.

Comment: A fix for this will be posted in the next production build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Patience? 22 hours is really fast for a not-major bug fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Same **[answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317189/3448527)** I gave on metaSO

> This is a network bug.
>
> Caused by this line in `all.css`:
>
> ```css
> .popup-badges .all-badge-progress .badge-progress` {
>   height:76px;
>   /*...other css*/
> }
> ```
>
> , a quick solution/fix would be to set the `height` to `98px` because
>   (at least on SO) the `p` child has the maximum of 3 lines, so `98px`
>   would be enough to have those 3 lines plus some bottom space and the
>   tag-badges would have enough space as well.

Answer (score 3):

I created [a userscript](https://gist.github.com/Gothdo/9a3e0c760066d978d302) to fix this issue temporarily:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Stack Exchange select badge fix
// @namespace    https://github.com/Gothdo
// @version      1.0
// @description  Fixes the issue described in a Meta.SE post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/275844/310998
// @author       Gothdo
// @match         *://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match         *://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match         *://superuser.com/*
// @match         *://meta.superuser.com/*
// @match         *://serverfault.com/*
// @match         *://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @match         *://askubuntu.com/*
// @match         *://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @match         *://stackapps.com/*
// @match         *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

$(function() {
  $("head").append(
      "<style>\n"
    + ".popup-badges .all-badge-progress .badge-progress {\n"
    + "  width: 214px;\n"
    + "  height: 96px;\n"
    + "}\n"
    + "</style>"
  );
});
```

You can install it by clicking [this link](https://gist.github.com/Gothdo/9a3e0c760066d978d302/raw/7a6a840d56a25fb677f8d0b30651e2f8e209a09d/se-select-badge-fix.user.js).