# Strange behaviour with badges

Tags: bug, badges, design

So, I was looking status of my badges and I've noticed that text is out of the borders. I thought it was because of zooming, but it's not, and it happens on all SO communities. Is there some problem with this? Some bug?

This is not same question as **[this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275844/next-badge-select-dialog-broken)** one. Thoose are badges that I gather in tags, these are other ones. It may be related, because of badges, but they are not the same badges or on the same part of site.

[image]

Comment: @PatrickHofman, this is different set of badges, did you read the question and saw the picture?

Comment: It is the exact same dialog, just with other content, right?

Comment: Yeah, but that dialog stands in other part. Not the same part.

Comment: It is the exact same thing, with the exact same bug, just with other content.

Comment: It may be in global css file, or in separate css file. I don't know what's the structure of it. But basically, they don't have same height for example. It's not the same stuff.It's different class, with different content and spacing. It's similar, but not the same.

Comment: therefore it's not a duplicate question because it's pointing on other file, and other stuff. Not the same as the previous.

Comment: @PatrickHofman It is not a duplicate.

Comment: @JosipIvic While the issues reported aren't the same, both are effects from a change we made with the box-sizing for popups on the user page this week. This and the other issue should be corrected now. Thanks for reporting the issue!